# Linux kernel: why does this call to kstrtol crash?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am learning kernel programming and have a simple call to kstrtol I am using to convert a string to a number. However, everytime I compile this module and use insmod to place it in the kernel, I get "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at f862b026" and then a register and stack dump.

I'm following the definition from here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kstrtol.html. It seems like a really simple call. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init convert(void)
{
    long myLong;
    char *myNumber = "342";
    myNumber[2] = '\0'; //Overwriting the '2', just so I know for sure I have a terminating '\0'

    if (kstrtol(myNumber, 10, &myLong) == 0)
    {
        printk("We have a number!\n");
    }
return 0;
}

static void __exit convert_exit(void)
{
    printk("Module unloaded\n");
}

module_init(convert);
module_exit(convert_exit);
```

Comment: The problem may be with overwriting the 2. Literals are not supposed to be modified.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify string literals. Copy it into an array firstly.

edit: use this instead

```
char mystr[] = "abdc";
```

edit2:
the underlying reason for this is, that a char pointer to a string literal points to a data segment, usually readonly. If you alter this memory you might get a crash.
When you create an array of chars instead, the string literal gets copied into the array on the stack, where you safely can modify it.

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to use char pointers for my strings, as eventually I'm going to need to parse parameter input coming into the module. I'm splitting a string (format like: 120;something) into the number and word. So, I store the number in a char *. How do I handle it in this case?

Comment: `char *mystr[] = "abcde"; char *myptr = mystr;`

Comment: The array will decay into a pointer in almost any situation, so it should be compatible.

Comment: @H2CO3, because I'm taking the paramater, for example param = "1234;something" and splitting it into two new strings (after I allocate the memory) 

strncpy(number, param, 0, 5) (and similar for the "something" part)

number[5] = '\0'; kstrtol(number, 10, &result) -- where result is a long.

Is this a bad approach? If so, what is the correct approach

Comment: @Maxthecat It's not a bad approach. But then you are working an array. Aren't you?