# Runtime error in the code

Tags: c++

In the following program to rotate a string run time error occurs .Please help

there are no compilation errors in the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void reverseString(char* str, int start, int end)
{
    int front = start;
    int back = end;
    while (front < back)
    {
        /* swap two variables without
        using a temporary one.*/
        str[front] ^= str[back];
        str[back]  ^= str[front];
        str[front] ^= str[back];
        ++front;
        --back;
    }
    return;
}
```

This part is for rotating the string

```
void rotateString(char* str, int k)
{
    if (!str || !*str)
        return;
    int len = strlen(str);
    /*Rotating a string by it's length is string itself.*/
    k %= len;
    reverseString(str, 0, len-1);
    reverseString(str, 0, k-1);
    reverseString(str, k, len-1);
    cout<<str;
    return;
}

int main() {
    rotateString("abcde",2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a readability/perceivability improvement: `str[front] ^= str[back];`

Comment: Not like this wasn't asked **literally 40 minutes ago** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186103/linux-kernel-why-does-this-call-to-kstrtol-crash#).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you try to modify a literal string. All literal strings are constant and read-only. Trying to modify one leads to *undefined behavior*, which can some times seem to work and some time crash.

Try instead e.g.

```
char str[] = "abcde";
rotateString(str, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string literal here:

```
rotateString("abcde",2);
```

and subsequently trying to modify it, this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The C++ draft standard in section `2.14.5` *String literals* says(*emphasis mine*):

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. **The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.**

this code on the other hand will work with invoking undefined behavior:

```
char arr[] = "abcde" ;
rotateString(arr,2);
```

Comment: The interesting point here is that the type of "abcd" is `char const [6]`. And it's being passed to a function accepting `char *`...

Comment: ...ah it turns out that C++03 allows interpretation of a string literal as `char *`: "A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [Note: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D. ]"

Comment: @IgorR. `gcc` and `clang` will warn but this to keep compatibility with *C* since string literals are `char[]` in *C*.

Comment: Yes. But AFAIR, C++11 drops this compatibility and disallows such an implicit conversion.

Comment: @IgorR. Both `gcc` and `clang` in *C++11* mode allow this with a warning saying it is depreciated ... although you can always make warnings an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 rotateString("abcde",2);
```

*You are passing a String Literal (which is a const) to rotateString(). Actually Compiler makes a constant temprory string variable/ char[] and stores "abcde" in it & passes it to the function rotateString().*

As you **can't edit/modify a const,** that why you are getting an error.

***Solution:***

```
Store "abcde" in a char[] and passing it to rotateString()
```